# AngularJS override (mock) services for unit test

Tags: angularjs

The scenario is very simple, I am trying to test a service A, which depends on service B, so I decided to mock service B by overriding it before I inject service A. However, I am also testing service B which is no longer valid since it is overridden. Any idea on how to avoid this?

Application code.

```
angular.module('MyApp.services')
  .factory('serviceB', function(){
    return {
      greeting: function(){ return 'hello'; }
    }
  })
  .factory('serviceA', ['serviceB', function(serviceB){
    return {
      greeting: function(){
        return 'I say: ' + serviceB.greeting();
      }
  });
```

Unit Test:

```
describe('My app services', function(){

  beforeEach(module('MyApp.services'));

  describe('service A', function(){
      // mock service B
    angular.module('MyApp.services').factory('serviceB', function(){
      return { greeting: function(){ return 'mocked B'; } }
    });

    var serviceA;

    inject(function(_serviceA_){
      serviceA = _serviceA_;
    });

    it('should work', function(){
      var words = serviceA.greeting();
      expect(words).toBe('I say: mocked B');          
    });
  });

  describe('service B'. function(){
    var serviceB;

    inject(function(_serviceB_){
      serviceB = _serviceB_;
    });

    it('should work', function(){
      var words = serviceB.greeting();
      expect(words).toBe('hello');
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your service injection should probably be either in a `beforeEach` or as part of the tests, otherwise I think they will happen before the tests begin or not at all, e.g.

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_serviceA_){
  serviceA = _serviceA_;
}));
```

or

```
it('should work', inject(function(serviceA){
    var words = serviceA.greeting();
    expect(words).toBe('I say: mocked B');          
}));
```

---

To solve the problem you are actually asking about, I suggest you do one of two things:

1. Override the service in the injector rather than the module

   ```
   beforeEach(module(function($provide){
     $provide.value('serviceB', {
       greeting: function(){ return 'mocked B'; }
     });
   }));
   ```

   See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wNYH4F0Bk4goiaD4jzr3?p=preview).
2. Use a separate module that can be added when needed to override `serviceB`

   Somewhere (that only needs to be called once), put the definition of your new module containing your mock version of `serviceB`

   ```
   angular.module('MyApp.services.mock', [])
     .factory('serviceB', function(){
       return { greeting: function(){ return 'mocked B'; } }
     });
   ```

   then where you currently alter the service in your module under test, use the following to load your module with the mock on top.

   ```
   beforeEach(module('MyApp.services.mock'));
   ```

   See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dS9eb1?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Override the service using spies rather than the module, then, when you are testing (unit test) service A, you only test service A, this means you can mock (spy) service B and assume you have a test for service B and is working.

Unit Test:

```
describe('My app services', function(){

  beforeEach(module('MyApp.services'));

  describe('service A', function(){
    var serviceA, serviceB;

    inject(function(_serviceA_, _serviceB_){
      serviceA = _serviceA_;
      serviceB = _serviceB_;
    });

    it('should work', function(){
      spyOn(serviceB, 'greeting').and.returnValue('TEST');

      var words = serviceA.greeting();

      expect(words).toBe(I say: TEST');
    });
  });

  describe('service B'. function(){
    var serviceB;

    inject(function(_serviceB_){
      serviceB = _serviceB_;
    });

    it('should work', function(){
      var words = serviceB.greeting();
      expect(words).toBe('hello');
    });
  });
});
```